# Como agrupar uma lista de objetos e apos o agrupamento, obter a lista de objetos que possuem o menor valor em c#?

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte estrutura :

```
namespace teste
{
    public class Produto
    {

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    }

    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listaDeProdutos = new List<Produto>();

            var obj1 = new Produto
            {
                Nome = "celular",
                Valor = 10
            };

            var obj2 = new Produto
            {
                Nome = "celular",
                Valor = 15
            };

            var obj3 = new Produto
            {
                Nome = "teclado",
                Valor = 20
            };

            var obj4 = new Produto
            {
                Nome = "teclado",
                Valor = 30
            };

            var obj5 = new Produto
            {
                Nome = "monitor",
                Valor = 15
            };

            listaDeProdutos.Add(obj1);
            listaDeProdutos.Add(obj2);
            listaDeProdutos.Add(obj3);
            listaDeProdutos.Add(obj4);
            listaDeProdutos.Add(obj5);

        }
    }
}
```

---

Gostaria de saber como a partir da minha `listaDeProdutos` obter uma nova lista de produtos com as seguintes regras:

> 1- A nova lista não pode ter produto de nome repetido.
>
> 2- A nova lista deve ter somete produtos de menor valor.

**Resultado esperado:**

A novaListaDeProdutos deve ter os seguinte objetos:

> [0] Nome = "celular", Valor = 10
>
> [1] Nome = "teclado", Valor = 20
>
> [2] Nome = "monitor", Valor = 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) fica simples assim:

```
var novaLista = listaDeProdutos.OrderBy(o => o.Valor).GroupBy(x => x.Nome)
    .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

[**Veja o exemplo funcionando no seu código.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NLpZbu)

Basicamente oque o código faz é:

1. Ordenar pelo valor em ordem crescente.
2. Agrupar pelos nomes dos produtos.
3. Selecionar a primeiro valor de cada grupo.
4. Retornar a nova lista

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção seria implementar o interface `IEqualityComparer<T>` e usar a extensão `Distinct()`:

```
public class Produto : IEqualityComparer<Produto>
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Produto x, Produto y)
    {
        return x.Nome.Equals(y.Nome);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Produto obj)
    {
        return obj.Nome.GetHashCode();
    }        
}
```

Para usar:

```
var novaListaDeProdutos = listaDeProdutos.OrderBy(x => x.Valor).Distinct(new Produto()).ToList();
```

[Veja funcionando no dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ahl6j)

Comment: +1 Muito bom! Só uma observação neste caso: a comparação sempre será verdadeira se os nomes forem iguais. E pode ser que nem sempre esse seja o comportamento esperado.